# Humanity is gone. What's the timeline of vermin infestation in an abandoned wholesale supermarket club?

Tags: science-based, post-apocalypse, earth, food, ecology

Due to an accident during a transdimensional handwavium experiment, every sentient being on Earth was whisked away into another dimension. Humans are gone in a fiat.

Somewhere, during temperate summer, near a highway exit, a wholesale supermarket club (think Costco, Sams' Club, and the like) is left for the vermin (urban rats, bugs, roaches, etc). All that delicious food is enticing.

What's the timeline of the vermin invasion on that warehouse of groceries? How much of the available food (as in still edible by a returning human) will be left after a week, a month, six months, and a year later?

Comment: Ummm, the vermin are already there. Much of the food will spoil without vermin, from bacteria, molds, and such. But Twinkies will still be edible for centuries. All the preservatives, no food value for even rodents.

Answer (score 6):

Fruits and veggies out of the fridge will immediately start growing fruit flies and will begin spoiling: they will be gone in days.

Meanwhile other insects will start the spoilage of any food at reach, helped by rodents who will chew away the packaging.

Frozen stuff will start to spoil as soon as the electricity network collapses due to lack of human intervention. However the freezer will be less accessible, unless some sufficiently dexterous animal ventures in the place. This will be a matter of days/weeks.

What is left is then canned and jarred food, which is too much for a rodent and also doesn't attract attention due to the lack of smell. Maybe some defective can will start fermenting and might explode. Also spirits might last longer, if nobody drops their bottles. They can last years.

I hope your returning human likes bourbons and beans.

Comment: If a bear would get to the supermarket, that would change things (but not really the timeline).

Answer (score 6):

Over the course of a year there's about a 10% chance of the sorts of roofing problems, that if left without repair, would see significant damage. If that were located over the food, water will soak through everything not sealed in plastic (in the US of course, things like coffee now are often completely sealed). There's less than a 1% chance of any sort of weather event that would smash the building or rip the roof off. So the leak itself would only spoil some of the food.

Anything requiring refrigeration, of course won't last the week, as electricity will be gone quickly (within a few days).

Canned goods (either in steel cans, or glass jars) can last a year or more, even if the printed expiration date is set lower (for political/bureaucratic reasons). These will be impervious to vermin.

Some dry goods will also survive. Pasta, flour, beans. Those that don't get hit by roof leaks will avoid water damage... and while rodents will happily ruin those, the big pallets are often wrapped in plastic for transport and left that way until forklifted down to the floor. The height, the plastic, and "discoverability" will protect these somewhat over the course of 12 months (or even 36).

Cooking oil, coffee, jams and jellies, snack chips, perhaps even (some) candy will last quite awhile. On the latter, I'd bet on those that seal the package (so no luck on Reese cups).

In any given store, some salvageable goods will remain for a long while.

Comment: The problem with vermin is that once they find a source of food, they will multiply, and they are resourceful enough to get on high shelves and chew through the plastic wrap. Thus I wouldn't count on any non-canned food to survive for long.

Comment: @Alexander Your concerns are valid, and that will happen. But for vermin, a "source of food" is the one single pallet with plastic wrap. It doesn't seem to occur to them that the pallet next to it wrapped in similar plastic is yet another source of food. This tends to mean that you'll see many pallets spoiled in such a store, but not all of them. At least for the rodents. Insects can behave differently, but need immediate sources of moisture.

Comment: With high number of rodents, all pallets will be spoiled before too long. Those creatures would gnaw through things for no apparent reason.

Comment: @Alexander My personal experience is that rodents/squirrels only do that out of spite, and with no humans around to fuck with, they'll probably stick to more rational patterns of exploration. Besides, the horizon for this question was 1 year out. I have no doubt that on a timetable of 5 years out that everything would be gone.

Answer (score 1):

a couple of issues spring to mind ..

1. electricity could be available for some weeks possibly even months after the people go poof. Modern electrical grids are 100 % automated so they would keep the freezers running until an accident breaks something (storm damage, electrical fault etc).
2. Vermin will already be in the building. There is no food storage building in the world that completely blocks access to  rats/mice/birds and likely there will be some already living in it.
3. Plastic wrapping reduces or eliminates oxidisation if it completely seals its contents.

Now lets consider how fast things will spoil

1. UHT or irradiated containers for liquids preserve their contents for years. It would take decades for the plastic boxes to degrade to the point they would leak.
2. The contents of tin (steel) cans, and glass jars with metal lids, will last until the metal is completely rusted through AND something disturbs the rust to allow air and spores through. This will take at least months, but probably years.
3. liquids in aluminium cans will be preserved until oxidisation weakens the metal enough that internal pressure bursts them. This will be at least months if they are in the open, years possibly even decades for cans in boxes sealed in plastic wrap.
4. Frozen foods will be perfectly preserved until the power goes out and their insulated storage units warm to thawing temperature. Freezers in Walmart/Costco sized stores are walk-in and are well sealed, thus blocking access to rodents until they can gnaw their way thru the insulation (low chances there). Thus the food contents will start turning to gross mush within a day or two of the power going out. Stuff in tub freezers will go the same way. Smaller freezers with glass doors may develop enough pressure that the door is cracked open which will speed the decomposition. On the whole, frozen food will be inedible 2-3 days after the loss of power.
5. wine in glass bottles with properly seated corks will last for decades of course. Cheaper wines in twist tops will oxidise and go bad within months and wine in boxes will be preserved until the plastic liner degrades enough that leakage occurs so that is years.
6. Dried Goods - flour will last till insect larvae eat it all, which could be months or years if it is properly packaged in sterile conditions and wrapped in plastic for shipping. If its processing is sub-standard it will already have insect eggs/larvae in the flour so would not last long. Obviously flour already on the shelves will go faster than the better protected packages in the store rooms.

- dried fruit will go like flour, good packaging and still in bulk storage weeks to months, on the shelf a few days till rodents get at it
- cookies and baked goods in paper packaging will be gone in days, weeks at most if there is a large amount to start with.

7. Fresh food will start to be eaten within a few hours of there being no people about to keep the rodents in hiding.

in short - a hungry returning person would be best advised to look for edible food in the centre of a skid loaded with plastic, metal or glass packages, wrapped in plastic in cool dark storage rooms. it is possible that usable food could still be found after 10 or more years.

Comment: Very unlikely electrical power would be around that long. Human intervention is needed for almost every thing. Timing would vary probably with coal plant in hours, natural gas electrical power because of pipelines a couple of days. Hydro and nuke power possibly longer, but nuke plant probably automatically trip off for safety reasons pretty quickly.  Some micro grids might last longer since simpler,  but in general wide availability of power would probably be gone quickly. Especially if there is a set of cascading events due to grid connectivity and complexity.

Comment: coal plants, if any would still exist, have to be fully automated so as long as the cola on hand lasts the machines can keep things running for 2-3 weeks. Hydro power can keep going for months without intervention .. Nuclear plants .. we really need facts from the industry for that part of the answer.
Hey @UVphoton new thought - distribution network would be the limiting factor. Any damage to power lines can lead to huge areas losing power, and possibly causing explosions in transformers from overloads a so .. I change my guess for how long power would remain to a week tops